# Split a long string into columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How  do I separate a long string and put them into three columns. Columns are separated by `|` and rows are separted by `,`

For example  string

```
Toronto|Ontario|Canada,Dallas|Texas|USA,New York|New York|USA,Windsor|Ontario|Canada
```

I have a table with 5 columns, 3 columns are City, State and Country.

I would like to seperate them and put those into categories

```
Continent          City            State        Country  Added

                    Toronto      Ontario     Canada

                    Dallas        Texas       USA

                    New York   New York       USA
```

Comment: Are you looking for in SQL query? If it were me I would just use Microsoft Excel import text and select the pipe as a delimiter, you may need to replace comma with newline char

Comment: Yes, SQL would be better. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Where's the string stored, in a text file? Also what kind of database are you using?

Comment: SQL 2012. This will be string variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this standard way. First split string to rows and then split each row to columns:

```
declare @s nvarchar(max) = 'a|b|c,d|e|f'

;with rows as(
  select x.t.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') r
  from (select cast('<x>'+replace(replace(@s,'|','.'),',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) d) t
  cross apply t.d.nodes('/x') x(t))

  select parsename(r, 3) as col1,
         parsename(r, 2) as col2,
         parsename(r, 1) as col3
  from rows
```

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3
a       b       c
d       e       f
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4220

Answer (score 0):

Check this example.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(500)  = 'Toronto|Ontario|Canada,Dallas|Texas|USA,New York|New York|USA,Windsor|Ontario|Canada'

SELECT 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, '|', '.'), 1) AS COUNTRY,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, '|', '.'), 2)  AS STATE,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, '|', '.'), 3)  
CITY
FROM
(SELECT 
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(500)') AS Data  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT
          CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@string, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data       
 ) AS A  
 CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
 ) b
```

Will give this answer.

```
COUNTRY     STATE       CITY        
Canada      Ontario     Toronto
USA         Texas       Dallas
USA         New York    New York
Canada      Ontario     Windsor
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, Use this -**

```
create table myTable (Continent varchar(30),City varchar(30),State 
varchar(30),Country varchar(30),Added varchar(30))

declare @input varchar(200)
set @input = 'Toronto|Ontario|Canada,Dallas|Texas|USA,New York|New 
              York|USA,Windsor|Ontario|Canada'
Declare @Qry Varchar(7000)      
Set @Qry = ''        
Select @Qry = @Qry + ' Insert into myTable (City,State ,Country) '    
Select @Qry = @Qry +  Replace( 'Select ''' + 
       Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(@input,CHAR(9),''),' 
       ',''),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') , ',',''' Union Select ''') + ''''           
set @Qry = replace(@Qry,'|',''',''')
Exec (@Qry) 

select * from myTable
```